# What is the cheapest way to upgrade from OS X10.4 to 10.6?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I have been living in the past, and it is finally catching up to me.
What is the cheapest way to upgrade from Mac OS X 10.4 to 10.6?

Answer (score 6):

Spend the 30 bucks to get the 10.6 DVD and then use it for a clean install.

There's no reason to buy 10.5 so you can "upgrade" to 10.6. The 10.6 DVD is exactly the same as all the other release DVDs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *cheapest* way to upgrade to Snow Leopard is to find someone who has a legal DVD but is no longer using it, and ask him/her to give it to you.

(Note: IANAL and I don't know if Apple's EULA "allows" such transfers, but you did ask for the *cheapest* way, and I'm assuming that you do not want to simply use Bittorrent.)

If it was me, I would definitely spend the $30 to [buy it from Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A).